# What's the best way to manipulate Boost INFO file in Python

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

I have a C++ program which read a [Boost INFO file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.info_parser) as a configuration file, and now I'm planning to dev a python script to manipulate those conf files. What's the best way to do it?

I can't find any existing module in python doing that, actually when I type Boost INFO and Python in Google, most of the results are not so relevant. I haven't even found a full syntax description of INFO.

And it's seems too much work to dev a parser in python or C++ extension for python to achieve this as I'm new to python.

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend switching the C++ program to use JSON instead since it is *really* close to INFO and readily parsed by most programming languages.

Comment: Yeah, I saved it as my last choice because I don't have control on the C++ part... and I'm not sure how much work it take to make the change. Thanks!

Comment: You could probably write a parser in Python pretty easily, but it is just the wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, but I needed this as well, so I wrote a parser class. It is available [here](https://gist.github.com/thecodemaiden/dc4e4e4a54eaa5f0be84). There is no error handling, but as long as your config file has correct syntax, it should be a good starting point.